# ifstream doesn't allow file to be renamed

Tags: c++, file, fopen, ifstream

I am creating a c++ application which is more similar to file tailer. I am reading the logs as it is being written. I am using ifstream to read the file. I have another process to write the sample logs(for me to read) and when the log file reaches a particular size I am renaming the file and continue writing in the file. But ifstream doesn't allow me to rename a file when it is reading. errno is 13(permission denied). Is there any way to stop ifstream when another process is trying to renmae it or is there any alternate to ifstream which allows the file to be renamed. 
NOTE: I don't want to change in the log writer since I will be reading third party logs.

Comment: Yes. Don't rename the file, don't move it. Copy the file into another file and clear it's content.

Comment: @KamilCuk . Thanks for your response. But I am saying that the log writer function is trying to rename the file and my application (ifstream) is not allowing it to do.

Comment: May be, another option could be to close and re-open the `ifstream` periodically (at best with a certain delay). So, the other process has a chance to slip in.

Comment: it'll be OS specific and will depend on the share mode of the file handle.
The portable (with c++ streams) way will be to close the ofstream, rename the file and re-open the ofstream.